# How to sort a data frame by multiple column(s) in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to sort a data frame by multiple columns.  Here is a simple data frame I made. How can I sort each column by a different sort type?

```
using DataFrames

DataFrame(b = ("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"),
      levels = ("Med", "Hi", "Low"),
      x = ("A", "E", "I", "O"), y = (6, 3, 7, 2),
      z = (2, 1, 1, 2))
```

Ported this over from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike R, Julia's DataFrame constructor expects the values in each column to be passed as a vector rather than as a tuple: so `DataFrame(b = ["Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"],` &tc.

Also, DataFrames does not expect explicit *levels* to be given in the way R does it. Instead, the optional keyword argument `categorical` is available and should be set to "a vector of Bool indicating which columns should be converted to CategoricalVector".

(after adding the DataFrames and the CategoricalArrays packages)

```
julia> using DataFrames, CategoricalArrays

julia> xyorz = categorical(rand(("x","y","z"), 5))
5-element CategoricalArray{String,1,UInt32}:
 "z"
 "y"
 "x"
 "x"
 "z"

julia> smallints = rand(1:4, 5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 2
 1
 1

julia> df = DataFrame(A = 1:5, B = xyorz, C = smallints)
5×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B            │ C     │
│     │ Int64 │ Categorical… │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼──────────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ z            │ 2     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ y            │ 3     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ x            │ 2     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ x            │ 1     │
│ 5   │ 5     │ z            │ 1     │
```

now, what do you want to sort? A on (B then C)? `[4, 3, 2, 5, 1]`

```
julia> sort(df, (:B, :C))
5×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B            │ C     │
│     │ Int64 │ Categorical… │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼──────────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 4     │ x            │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 3     │ x            │ 2     │
│ 3   │ 2     │ y            │ 3     │
│ 4   │ 5     │ z            │ 1     │
│ 5   │ 1     │ z            │ 2     │

julia> sort(df, (:B, :C)).A
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 3
 2
 5
 1
```

This is a good place to start http://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/

Comment: Jeffrey, I particularly appreciated the "from R" approach, perfect for me (and others, I hope). In [Przemyslaw Szufel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920641) above, the frame reference used a vector `[:z,:y]` vice your use of a tuple `(:B, :C)`. While I'm guessing this is more of a "slight-efficiency" thing, is there another compelling reason to use tuples over vectors?

Comment: In DataFrames.jl a general design is to use vectors. In this case using a tuple is allowed but will not add efficiency here, as internally it is converted to a vector anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was creating a single row `DataFrame` containing a tuple so I corrected it. 
Note that for nominal variables you would normally used `Symbol`s rather than `String`s.

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(b = [:Hi, :Med, :Hi, :Low, :Hi],
               x = ["A", "E", "I", "O","A"], 
               y = [6, 3, 7, 2, 1],
               z = [2, 1, 1, 2, 2])

sort(df, [:z,:y])
```

Comment: As an additional note - as hinted by Jeffrey Sarnoff for nominal or ordinal columns a typical approach would be to use `CategoricalVector`.